# Copy to clipboard for basic html

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard

I am new to programming and I have basic HTML skills.
I am creating a basic web site and I have information in a paragraph and the information is separated by `<br>` tags. I am looking to add a "copy to clipboard" button and function so that the 16 lines of information are saved to the clipboard.

```
<p>
this is the 1st line<br>
this is the 2nd line<br>
...
this is the 16th line [copy to clipboard]
<p>
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far, and where did you get stuck? Also, see the "related" section over there on the right? Have you tried any of those answers?

Comment: I remember trying this before but could not find a solution using JS. You need to use flash

Comment: Flash may not be best going forward since support for it is dropping due to all the security issues.

Comment: Thank you j08691. I tried the solution given by http://davidwalsh.name/clipboard..and I watched and tried to copy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xH_ZV0h4iYU...I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Thank you j08691. I see the function copytoclipboard on several sites and I would like to be able to place my 16 lines of data in the clipboard...I do excel and some vba but I am new to Html and web languages. I appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In browsers that support [`document.execCommand('copy')` and `document.execCommand('cut')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand), copying to the clipboard is very simple; you just do something like this:

```js
var copyBtn = document.querySelector('#copy_btn');
copyBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  var urlField = document.querySelector('#url_field');
  // select the contents
  urlField.select();     
  document.execCommand('copy'); // or 'cut'
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="url_field" type="url" value="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802082/copy-to-clipboard-for-basic-html">
<input id="copy_btn" type="button" value="copy">
```

The above is cribbed straight from [JavaScript Copy to ClipBoard (without Flash) using Cut and Copy Commands with document.execCommand()](http://codetheory.in/javascript-copy-to-clipboard-without-flash-using-cut-and-copy-commands-with-document-execcommand/).

If you press **Run code snippet** above the press the **copy**, you’ll see that takes the URL in the input field there (the URL for this StackOverflow question), and copies it to your clipboard.